# TPLINK W841ND PPPOE not working

Tags: networking

My ISP gave me a pppoe username and password.. My tplink router wr841nd sometimes can connect with these, sometimes not it shows connecting. Even though if I try to connect via pppoe on my laptop it can connect but not on router. How to solve this problem?

Comment: If the router has been provided by your ISP you can ask them to replace it. Might help. Otherwise try a factory reset and configure it once again.

Comment: I have bought the router, ISP didn't provide it, I just need to be sure that this problem occurs just because of the router. I have done factory reset, but same things happening.

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution for this issue? I have the same issue and my ISP is speedy/indihome.

Comment: No, I couldn't. Bought new router then.